# Group values and ordinally label groups Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains repetitive houses ids`house_id`.
I want to group the similar houses ids as `family_label`and give them an **ordinal label**.

My original data looks like this

> df_original = pd.DataFrame({'house_id':['112', '119', '913', '514',
> '112', '119', '119']})

```
house_id
112
119
913
514
112
119
119
```

My target result looks like the below dataframe

> df_result = pd.DataFrame({'house_id':['112', '119', '913', '514',
> '112', '119', '119'],
> 'family_label':['family1', 'family2', 'family3', 'family4', 'family1', 'family2', 'family2']})

```
house_id     family_label
112          family1
119          family2
913          family3
514          family4
112          family1
119          family2
119          family2
```

So far this is what I have achived.

I used this code

```
df_original['label'] = df_original.groupby(df_original.house_id).grouper.group_info[0]+1
```

it generates the below output

```
house_id  label
112        1
119        2
913        3
514        4
112        1
119        2
119        2
```

I want to know if my approach is correct and **I want to add the word 'family' before each number.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and precede `family` string. Such as:

```
 df_original['label'] = ["family"+str(x) for x in (df_original.groupby(df_original.house_id).grouper.group_info[0]+1)]
```

Outputting:

```
  house_id    label
0      112  family1
1      119  family2
2      913  family4
3      514  family3
4      112  family1
5      119  family2
6      119  family2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df_original['label'] = "family"+(df_original.groupby('house_id').ngroup()+1).astype(str)
print (df_original)
  house_id    label
0      112  family1
1      119  family2
2      913  family4
3      514  family3
4      112  family1
5      119  family2
6      119  family2
```

Comment: @Myaccount - `ngroup` is not possible use?